# Generic Exception Handler in a Controller catches @RequestBody validation exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a RestController like below, which has a generic Exception handler. However the problem is it catches the validation Exceptions from `@RequestBody` such as `MethodArgumentNotValidException` and other related exceptions.

```
@RestController
class QRController {

    @PostMapping("/customer")
    fun handleRequest(@Valid @RequestBody customer: Customer) {
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception::class)
    fun handleException(e: Exception) {
        // It catches exceptions form @Requestbody exceptions
    }
}
```

I believe one way is to make a new controllerAdvice extending from `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` however I was thinking if It's possible to it in the controller class itself.

How to make the generic exception handler not handle body validation exceptions?

EDIT: added argument to method and fixed typos

Comment: Why are you using a a generic exception handler like that? It's generally an anti-pattern to catch all Exceptions. Only catch exceptions you know will happen.